# How can I copy Brightcove players and in-page experiences from one account to another?

Tags: brightcove

I've been developing Brightcove players and in-page experiences in a development account while building a proof of concept.  Now that stakeholders have agreed to move forward, I need those players and in-page experiences copied to a production account.  How can I do this?

I don't see any options in Video Cloud to allow this, and I don't see anything in any API that lets me download a definition, say, in JSON.  I'd rather not have to manually recreate my players and in-page experiences in the Video Cloud screens, since I'm likely to make an error.

Related: I'd also like to be able to download definitions for these players and IPXes so that I can store them in version control, just like I would any other component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The player and in-page experience configurations are retrievable using the [Player Management API](https://support.brightcove.com/quick-start-player-management) and [In-Page Experience API](https://support.brightcove.com/overview-page-experience-api).

These REST APIs will return both configurations as JSON objects which can then be stored in version control and/or published into new/different accounts (after changing the account ids, and other account-specific information).

Also, in the Players Module in the Studio, you can view the specific JSON for that player by editing the player and using the JSON Editor.

Let me know if this helps!

Disclaimer: I am employed by Brightcove

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will do the trick.  I'm piping the JSON into `jq . --sort-keys` to pretty it up and make it more diff-friendly for storing in our VCS.

Comment: The IPX API link is now: https://apis.support.brightcove.com/ipx/getting-started/overview-page-experience-api.html